# Java: how to split string with leading numbers in java

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string, like

```
12abcdef
1ab2cdef
abcdef
```

string can start with number or without number but 
I need to split it into two parts, first number(if any) and second string

I need to split the string as [12,abcdef] [1,ab2cdef][abcdef]

How can I do this in java? which regex expression should I use with spilit in java?

Comment: use `split` using regex for number - try something at https://regex101.com/

Comment: learn regex, it will be very useful for this and many other problems http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: `str.split("(?<=^\\d*)(?!\\d)", 2)`

Comment: @shmosel when I checked the regex you provided, it gave error in *. while testing in regerx101.com

Comment: It worked in Java.

Comment: @user8937225 Why use regexr to test Java regex if it does not support this regex flavor? If you want to test Java regex online to see **if it works**,  use http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex with capturing groups, and a `Matcher`, like this:

```
String s = "12abcdef";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]*)([^0-9]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.matches()){
    System.out.println("Digits = \"" + m.group(1) + "\"");
    System.out.println("Non-digits = \"" + m.group(2) + "\"");
} else 
    System.out.println("No match");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to solve this, split is a good starter. Here is a working example which will handle your user case.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(splitString("12abcdef"));
        System.out.println(splitString("1ab2cdef"));
        System.out.println(splitString("abcdef"));
    }

    private static String splitString(String string) {
        String[] split = string.split("[a-z]");

        return split.length >= 1 ? split[0] : "";
    }
}
```

This will return either the numbers, or a blank string if no numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you exactly want using java `regex`:

```
public class SplitNumStr {
    private final static Pattern NUM_STR_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(\\w+)");
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("12absc", "2bbds", "abc"));
        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split(s)));
        }
    }

    private static String[] split(String numStr) {
        Matcher matcher = NUM_STR_PATTERN.matcher(numStr);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return new String[] {matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2)};
        } else return new String[] { numStr };
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
[12, absc]
[2, bbds]
[abc]
```

Answer (score -1):

Just count the continuous numbers and use `String.substring`.

```
static String[] test(String s) {
    int e = 0;
    while (e < s.length() 
        && '0' <= s.charAt(e)
        && s.charAt(e) <= '9')
        e++;
    return e == 0 || e == s.length() ? 
        new String[] { s } : 
        new String[] { s.substring(0, e), s.substring(e) };
}
```